# Point of inflection of vertical tangent

Tags: limits, derivatives

I know that continuous functions such as $$x^{1/3}$$ has a point of inflection of vertical tangent in $x=0$.

I don't know however how it is considered for non-continuous functions such as $$\frac{1}{1-x}$$
I mean. The derivative is also $+∞$ both for $\operatorname{lim}_ {x->1+}$ and for$\operatorname{lim}_{ x->1-}$

So I would say it is Ppoint of inflection of vertical tangent. But i'm not sure.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For $\frac{1}{1-x}$ as $x\to 1$ the function diverges at $\pm\infty$ and the tangent is not defined.

In this case we say that the function has a [vertical asymptote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote) at that point.

Answer (score 0):

No, $x=1$ is not a point of inflection for $$f(x)=\frac {1}{1-x}$$

Note that $x=1$ is not in the domain of your function to be considered a point of inflection.

While the concavity changes as you go through the asymptotic discontinuity, you never get into a real value for $x=1$

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the fast reply. Why is it not considered a point of inflection? Just because it is not continuous or because we have no real value for x=1? Because if it was something defined for interval, like this example (https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/ww5xawze), it could have a real value for x=1, and still be non-continuous with both the limits of right and left derivative equal to +∞

Comment: The graph relates to $y=x^{1/3}$ where the function does have a point of inflection at $x=0$

Comment: For $y=1/{(1-x)}$ the function is not defined so there is no point on the graph to be  considered an inflection point.

Answer (score 0):

The usual definitions of "point of inflection" require the function to be at least continuous at the point in question.  Some texts may also require it to be differentiable there.